# ffmpeg refuses to compile for x86_64 arch on M1 mac

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation

I'm trying to build a universal binary of ffmpeg on MacOS, by compiling it twice (for arm64 and x86_64) and then using the lipo tool to combine the resulting binaries. I'm on an M1 Mac, so `uname -m` returns `arm64` on my machine.

When running the configure script like so:

```sh
./configure --arch=x86_64
```

It outputs:

```
install prefix            /usr/local
source path               .
C compiler                gcc
C library                 
ARCH                      c (generic)
...
```

And after running `make`, inspecting the built binaries with `lipo -archs` reveals that it's building them for `arm64`.

The result is the same if I add `--enable-crosscompile` to the configure call.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281055/ffmpeg-compilation-with-arch-x86-64-always-compiles-with-x86), I also tried `--arch=x86`, but that had the exact same result, configure script displayed arch as `c (generic)` and inspecting artefacts with lipo shows they are built for `arm64` architecture.

Does anyone have any ideas? Why is the configure script just refusing to build for x86_64?

Comment: ffmpeg's build system is not Autotools-based.  Tags edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speify `-cc` to make clang compile x86_64 binary.
Try:

```sh
./configure --enable-cross-compile --prefix=./install_x86_64 --arch=x86_64 --cc='clang -arch x86_64'
```

Note: don't forget to clear the outdated files by

```sh
make distclean
```

By the way, I have successfully built universal binrary of FFmpeg, you can refer to my build [scripts](https://github.com/ColorsWind/FFmpeg-macOS). `make_compile.py` compile both `x86_64` and `arm64` binraries, and `make_universal.py` use `lipo` to generate universal binrary.

Reference

https://ffmpeg.org/platform.html

https://github.com/FFmpeg/gas-preprocessor

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. I was pulling my hair out trying to wrangle FFmpeg's configure script, I really wish they would just use Cmake... but this worked, thanks again!

Comment: On M1, using configure for cross compiling for static x86_64 libraries, I get the error : nasm/yasm not found or too old. Use --disable-x86asm for a crippled build. Any idea ? I looked at your repo which is amazing, but you didn't seem to have that problem ?

Comment: Oh nevermind sorry, I found [this random answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64110269/7360943) which simply suggests installing yasm with brew ```brew install yasm```